# Save status of DB row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am newbie to PHP.
I have admin panel (Backstage), created on Laravel.
On panel shows list of bids (demos) from MySQL table (demos).

I have deleted all html from code below.

Here is code that shows every row from table in demo view:

```
@foreach($listDemos as $demo)
  {{ $demo->id }}
  {{ $demo->name }}
  {{ $demo->email }}
  {{ $demo->link }}
  {{ $demo->created_at }}
@endforeach
```

Here is controller for demos

```
public function demo()
    {
      $listDemos = Demo::all();
      return view('backstage.demos')->with('listDemos', $listDemos);
    }
```

Here is route for demos:

```
Route::get('backstage/demos', 'BackstageController@demo');
```

I have another mysql table (demoStatus) with 2 columns

```
id and status
```

**The question is how to store status (Decline) in different table (demoStatuswhere id = demo id from demo table and status = button value) by clicking button in demo view:**

```
@foreach($listDemos as $demo)
  {{ $demo->id }}
  {{ $demo->name }}
  {{ $demo->email }}
  {{ $demo->link }}
  {{ $demo->created_at }}

  <form action="" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit">Decline</button>
  </form>
@endforeach
```

CSRF field stored at the head of every page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

For demoStatus I have another model:

```
class DemoStatus extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'demosStatus';
    protected $fillable = 'status';
}
```

and model for demos:

```
class Demo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'demos';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to send that `demo id` on from submit. One way of doing that is to use hidden field.

```
<form action="some/action/here" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="demo_id" value="{{ $demo->id }}" />
    <button type="submit">Decline</button>
</form>
```

The route this post is submitted to. Get this demo id and do whatever you want to do

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to use this instead of ->with();

```
public function demo()
    {
      $listDemos = Demo::all();
      return view('backstage.demos',['listDemos'=>$listDemos]);
    }
```